# Free RAM Optimizer (Booster) for Windows

Tags: windows, defragmentation

Sometimes I feel my PC is slow because I have runed some programs and probably fragmentation of the RAM.
I need a software for windows which is

- Free
- Realtime Monitoring (Low memory and CPU usage)

Comment: RAM, or **random** access memory, doesn't significantly degrade in performance by being fragmented, like a hard disk drive will. If the programs you run cause you to fill all available RAM and force the system to use swap (which is using hard disk space to simulate slower extra RAM) you will notice a significant slow down. If this is the case, the solutions are to close programs/reboot, reinstall the OS, and finally add more RAM to avoid spilling over into swap.

Comment: Then I suspect what means realtime monitoring advertized by some PC optimizers like the one recommended by rrirower

Comment: "Realtime monitoring" simply means getting to see what is happening to your computer as it happens.

Answer (score 3):

I will answer your question in two parts:

First: If I would be in your situation, I would use the free version of [Wise Memory Optimizer](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wisememoryoptimizerfree.html) and watching the difference, if it actually helps or not.

Second: I'm very sure the problem is something else, and it needs a little wall of text to fully explain it.

I'm going to assume you are using Windows 7 or 8.1. If your system boots up and you have a normal harddrive installed in your computer, the service [Superfetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperFetch) will load highly accessed files from previous boot startups and program activity into your RAM. This will make sure that if you're starting a program which you are probably going to use, it will load a lot faster. If you are going to use for example virtual machines which will take up 80% of your RAM, Windows will release the requested amount of memory which it has used to precache the Superfetch data, if there isn't "real" free RAM memory left. To take a look at your current RAM usage, open up the [Resource Monitor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-resource-monitor) in Windows and switch to the "Memory" tab. You will see this:

[image: memory tab of Resource Monitor]

"Hardware Reserved", "In Use" and "Modified" are used RAM by programs which you could free up by closing them, or if Windows will swap their contents to the harddisk due to low memory. This procedure is seriously slow, and Windows 7 will (from my experience) do this already if 70% of RAM is used. I guess this is the slowness from your experience.
"Standby" memory means that it's data cached by Superfetch and previously closed programs. "Free" memory is really free, waiting for content. If a (bad) RAM optimizer clears up the Standby memory to Free memory, then the benefit of Superfetch is killed for your current Windows session. And you will have huge slowdowns, because Windows needs to load every single file from the harddrive again. In this case, free memory is wasted memory.

RAM memory doesn't need defragmentation like classic harddrives, because it has no write head circling around. That's the same reason [why SSDs don't need defragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Comparison_with_hard_disk_drives) If you would do it anyway, it would reduce the lifespan. [Here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2061-myth-defragment-memory) is another informative link why RAM defragmentation isn't recommended.

TL;DR: Windows memory managment is fine, RAM Optimizers won't help like expected. You should better take a look if you can remove unnecessary programs from startup with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and disable unwanted or rarely used explorer shell extensions with [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Thanks for reading! And please feel free to correct any (spelling) mistakes or wrong facts if you have better knowledge than I have.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you 2 softwares which provides you the facility to optimize your RAM - [Baidu PC Faster](http://www.pcfaster.com/en/) and [IOBit Advanced System Care](http://www.iobit.com/advancedsystemcareper.html). Both provides you a widget type thing (usually situated on upper right or right side of the screen) to optimize RAM in real time. CCleaner is not a good choice because it does not provide option to optimize RAM in real time.

Comment: Actually, CCleaner does provide real time system monitoring.

Comment: @rrirower I said CCleaner does not provide real time RAM optimization, not system monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm going to recommend may **not** resolve your problem.  There are many reasons why your pc is not performing optimally.  But, [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) (free version) does optimize your pc in several ways including cache and registry cleanup.  Those two areas can impact the performance of your pc.  However, I would recommend that you try to pinpoint what the cause is before trying any solution.  You might want to run a system monitor to help with that.

Comment: "Those two areas can impact the performance of your pc" - Yes, negatively. Emptying caches could potentially slow down your computer, while cleaning the registry will do nothing at all. CCleaner will never, in any way, boost system performance.

Comment: @nanny Clearly an opinion I disagree with.  Let's see what happens to your system after installing and uninstalling software.  Take a peek at that pristine registry.

Comment: Okay, so what if the registry isn't pristine? That doesn't affect performance at all.

Comment: @nanny A registry that grows in size **can** affect performance.  Never mind the fact that some entries may no longer be valid.

Comment: "A registry that grows in size can affect performance." How? You're just blindly asserting that as fact when it has no basis in reality. "Never mind the fact that some entries may no longer be valid." True, but that isn't "system performance" and it's an extremely rare occurrence that it affects the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18809/discussion-between-nanny-and-rrirower).