# Free RAM Booster for Mac

Tags: gratis, osx, memory-management

I feel that my mac needs more RAM, but I can not afford that right now. I need a free RAM booster etc. for my mac.

My requirements:

- Free
- For mac
- Little CPU usage (I want to run other programs)

There is a related question, ([Free RAM Optimizer (Booster) for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/free-ram-optimizer-booster-for-windows)) for Windows but that does not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running a recent version of Mac OS X, **you don't need it.**

More specifically, if you're running Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) or later, memory compression is included:

**Sources:**

- [Apple](https://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/) - Mac OS X Advanced Technologies (scroll down to see "Compressed Memory.")
- [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/17/) - Review of 10.9

Comment: This is the only answer that matters. All "RAM Booster" programs are snake oil.

Comment: Actually, I didn't realize until the question was asked that there *are* "memory optimizer" and "RAM booster" apps for OS X.